# Similar, but not identical, question

Tags: support

I'm pretty new to StackOverflow and I want to know what I should do when my question is very similar to another question, but not identical. Should I ask my question in the thread itself or should I open a new thread?

Comment: Good guidance on Meta.SE: [What should I do if I have a sub-question to someone elses already existing question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174714)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see that.

Comment: No need to apologize; I was just linking to further reading for anyone who was interested.

Comment: If we were a forum and had threads, staying in the relevant thread might have helped. We instead have questions and answers, so a new question which is clearly different is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask your own question, but link to a similar one if it helps the situation.

Comment: If you already know your question is similar, take a little time to explicitly disambiguate your post -- with **more** than just a link. @ljnissen

Answer (score 1):

Simple.  Just use this guide:

- Does that question answer my question?

  - If *yes*: *No need to ask.*
  - If *no*: Can you mold it to answer your question?

    - If *yes*: Do you have any further questions?

      - If *yes*: Find duplicates and return to step one.
      - If *no*: *No need to ask.*
    - If *no*: Ask your question and make sure to mention the non-duplicate and explain why it did not answer your question.

If your question is significantly different from the duplicate, odds are that it will help other users as well.  Therefore, you should ask it.