# How to handle the "questions quite similar, but not identical" situations?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

While wandering around, I fell onto [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403732/how-to-check-if-array-is-empty-or-does-not-exist) question, asking about "how to check that an array is empty or does not exist". This question has already a large impact, however, it is voted as duplicate for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961528/how-to-check-if-an-array-exists-and-create-it-otherwise) question, which asks if "array exists, and create it otherwise".

Although extremely similar, they are not the same questions: The aim of this question is to make a conditional check, while the aim of the second one is to create an array on conditional existence, actually negating the first question in a sense.

I know one can think with ease "Come on, it is obvious that this is a duplicate!" or "This is way too simple", or even "Can't you see they are the same thing?". However, I consider it a case that a even such a simple question is **EXTREMELY** similar, but **NOT** identical in those cases. According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261037/similar-but-not-identical-question) meta answer, the duplicate question could simply mention the original one and this could be fine.

Community, my purpose is not to find out if this specific question is duplicate or not - but I consider it a grey zone example, and I would like to open a discussion on this: *How do we handle such cases as a community?*

Do we follow the logic "if the first covers the second, then it's a duplicate" (which, can be considered as the case here)? Or do we act upon will in a democratic way, each one voting at personal opinion for closing/re-opening?

I would like to hear your opinions on this, in general, out of the context of this question. Thanks!

*Update:* To highlight the ambiguity, I mention that, the solution proposed `var arr = arr || [];` By Brian Campbell in the first question, does *not* answer the later one, the semantics are slightly different.

*Update #2:* I believe also that the best answer to the duplicate question is well-structured and of high quality, therefore *it adds to the topic*.
Also, some food for thought in this [SO blog some ages back](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/29/handling-duplicate-questions/). Also, check out [this topic in Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled). :)

Comment: Questions can be asked differently or have nuanced variations... it's the solutions that matter. In question you refer to isn't the real problem checking the existing?

Comment: You are right and it is, however, I am curious if typically we should close such a question, or just leave it open and refer the older one along. This is not limited to this question, my point is in a more generic matter: "What is the point that one question should be closed as duplicate, even if it slightly deviates another?"

Comment: Questions marked duplicate don't disappear. SO's goal is to create a knowledge base, not answer nuanced variations of the same questions over and over. Suppose someone else comes along and finds your referenced question but they also have another variation. By looking at current one *and* following the duplicate link doesn't that give them an even better chance of solving their issue?

Comment: @charlietfl my point is that the question is slightly different, therefore typically we should not mark them as duplicate. Check my update inside my question. There can be answers to the first question that do not answer the second. But this is to they typical extent, since practically, it is so close that it can be considered as dupe.

Comment: There are 8 answers in the duplicate. Just because one answer may not fit I simply can not see how being provided all the variations is a negative to future readers. You seem to have a misconception that marking questions as duplicates is counter productive to the goals of the site. If it is a new question and OP (or other members) can substantiate that the duplicate is of no use it is easy to reopen. Are there grey areas? Certainly. Is erring on the side of alternate approaches bad or wrong?

Comment: @charlietfl with all the respect I disagree. I believe also that the best response in the dupe question contributes greatly to the original question - therefore, *it adds value to the topic*. But my point is not focused on this question, rather on how we handle such cases in general. We have focused on one case, rather than trying to find a good, well-measured attitude on this.
Some food for thought: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/29/handling-duplicate-questions/

Comment: @charlietfl "Is erring on the side of alternate approaches bad or wrong?"
Probably it is not, and I find the discussion highly constructive on this - thanks to you and everyone for taking the time to discuss it.
To me, I judge the dupe questions by their high quality answers, at times. If we see that there is value there, then the dupe should remain active with a link to the first answer - and I believe this is the particular case.

Comment: Ok but it seems from this and from [another recent similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399291/this-is-why-i-so-strongly-disagree-with-stack-overflows-long-standing-implement) that there is a misconception that the content is no longer active. The only thing not active is new answers, otherwise the content exists for all. You found that question didn't you? Did you have a better solution to add that wouldn't cross over all the alternatives and be  useful for future readers?

Comment: There is one other benefit to marking duplicates that is trying to get askers to do more research when they ask questions that have been asked many many times. It gets really tiresome seeing many questions where it is really obvious that little to no research has been done before asking

Comment: You are right that the content remains active, however, should it close? Is it an exact duplicate? Based on this [Meta SE question and guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) it is not an exact dupe.
To clarify this: I am in favor of dupe voting/closing - however I am skeptical on whether or not it should be applied in variations of the original question that contain high-quality answers, especially if the variation gives space for different, high quality answers.
There is no question if the variation leaves no space for this.

Comment: Getting into nuance now though. Suppose it was reflected as 2 questions... 1) How to check array exists/length and 2) How to create new one if not. The dup clearly answers the first and the second is trivial and super easy to research. Another link could be added to dups( can have multiple dups) that answers the second part

Comment: How about we just close it as a duplicate of [Check if an array is empty or exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11743392/215552) and call it a day? Or [How to detect if a variable is an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1058427/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey It was originally marked as dup until this question caused people to open it pointlessly and thus remove the dup link

Comment: @heretic I agree. This is the right solution.

Comment: @charlietfl I expect it was due to the "impedance mismatch" between the two questions. The problem, as I see it, is that people spend so much time and effort arguing about a specific duplicate when there's almost always other choices for duplicate target, especially in JavaScript. If people would spend more time trying to find a duplicate that meets the needs of the asker, rather than arguing about whether the current proposed duplicate is 100% accurate, questions which should be closed as a duplicate would stay closed as duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>These two are different questions and they should remain open.</s>

I agree with Heretic Monkey that

[How to check if array is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403732/how-to-check-if-array-is-empty)

should be closed as a duplicate of

[Check if an array is empty or exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743392/check-if-an-array-is-empty-or-exists)

---

One question asks how to check whether a variable is a non-empty array and the other asks how to define a variable to be an empty array if it is not defined as an array yet.

Solutions might be similar but are actually different.

Here is how this two are different in my opinion:

**How to create an array if it doesn't exist yet:**

```
let a = Array.isArray(a) ? a : [];
```

**How to perform some action if a variable is a non-empty array:**

```
if(Array.isArray(a) && a.length){
    console.log("It's an array of size: ", a.length);
}
```

Comment: Opinions will vary if you consider that as a two step question. The first step is answered by the dup and the second is  beyond easy to research. The term duplicate should not be considered as a literal absolute match. The canonical question [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) will rarely match the OP code as "duplicate" but the principles are the main point of solutions and explaining the problem

Comment: @charlietfl "easy to research" yet there are several gotchas: the array isn't an array but has .length, the object is null, the object is an array like, etc.

Comment: @Braiam From both questions `Array.isArray()` covers those gotchas

Comment: @charlietfl Which is only accidental.

Comment: @Braiam Not sure what you mean by accidental

Comment: @charlietfl that the mere fact that is there, doesn't mean that someone would ever think about using it in the other scenario. It's accidental that someone through "hey, maybe I should make sure that the array I'm creating is an actual array" which the other scenario you should make sure.

Comment: @Braiam How to create a valid array is not easily researched? I think people not accepting this scenario as a duplicate are thinking only about the actual code in the question itself and not about future readers who benefit from the dup link as part of the knowledge base

Comment: @charlietfl you are putting way too much faith in readers. The fact that the "duplicate" has more views than the target should be enough to tell you otherwise. And no, I don't accept them as duplicate because they are conceptually different questions.

Comment: After some considerable discussion about this in SOCVR, I feel that the new duplicate target you refer to here (found by Heretic Monkey) is a far better dupe target. However, I don't really feel like now offering a reopen vote (which would be the third), just so that the question can be closed again. Better to wait for a Gold-Hammer or Moderator to change the dupe target.

Answer (score -1):

By clarifying and making sure those differences are front and center. As you correctly point out there are several gotchas with the questions asked: one of them is merely interested that the array exist at some point in time, the other that only process the array if there is something to process (or there isn't anything to process and populate it). This is why I instead would edit both questions to ask organically different things:

- How to properly create a probably non-existing array
- How to make sure my array contains something

I've proposed both scenarios as edits to the questions. Maybe I should use those titles and put an use case scenario (ie. that since the array is doesn't have elements the processing should be no-op). That would make both questions more useful and distinct.

Answer (score -1):

Question OP here. It is very interesting to see how the community responded to such a situation. I noticed that there were many different opinions about what "duplicate" means and how it should be treated.

My verdict on this, is that we have a situation of "the letter and the spirit of the law". One can say that typically the question is not a duplicate but in practice it can be considered as one, due to high similarity and context.
On the other hand, there were answers in the duplicate post that added value to the original post. One could also argue that both questions could be answered differently, or even that some answers apply to one question and not in another. Also, one could argue that the "dupe" question added value to someone searching about this, considering its impact and votes.

Honestly, I believe we thought about this *way, way too much*. A "duplicate" of something can be an **exact copy** compared to something else, but in this case, how "exact" it was, was well questioned. I believe both sides had valid points. Personally from now on, I am going to respond in such cases by what I think that something is duplicate, despite if it is an exact copy of something else - always with a grain of salt and with respect to the others. And if I am proven right or wrong, others might agree or disagree, *respectfully*.

Finally, I also believe the solution Heretic Monkey suggested is the best - the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403732/how-to-check-if-array-is-empty) suggested is a much better match in terms of duplication. I requested a mod intervention for this, and I hope that it will be considered for a change.

*Rejoice people,* we found the first "**Schrödinger's question**" - being duplicate and non-duplicate at the same time, heavily affected by each observer, each new time. :D